# UNION causes SQL statement to run a lot slower

Tags: sql, union

I wrote a SQL statement, the individual statements work well, but when I combine them using UNION the statement takes dramatically longer to run.  Is there an error that I am missing or a way to make this faster?

```
select bundle.bundle, bundle.week, bundle.sched_dt, dropper_assign.dropper_id 
from bundle, dropper_assign
where bundle.bundle not in 
    (select bundle from forecast_entry)
and bundle.week = dropper_assign.week
and bundle.sched_zip3 = dropper_assign.zip3
and bundle.sched_dt = dropper_assign.sched_date
and bundle.project_cd = dropper_assign.project_code
and dropper_assign.dropper_id <> 10002
and bundle.project_cd = 'EXFC'

union

select bundle.bundle, bundle.week, bundle.sched_dt, splits.dropper_id
from bundle, splits
where bundle.bundle not in 
    (select bundle from forecast_entry)
and bundle.bundle = splits.bundle
and splits.dropper_id <> 10002
and bundle.project_cd = 'EXFC';
```

Comment: if you are sure there are not duplicates, use `UNION ALL` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UNION` takes two data sets and returns the unique overlap.  In other words, it spends time removing duplicates.

`UNION ALL`, however, does not compare the result sets to remove the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

UNION will apply a DISTINCT filter on the final result, which, on large data sets, can be an expensive operation.